# getWorkInfosByTagLiveData not triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm having a problem, I can't seem to figure out why my code has stopped working.
I have a scheduler that has 2 functions, one for scheduling a work, and the other one returns a livedata for the works currently running.

I schedule my work like this (I cut the last part as it is not relevant for the problem) :

```
workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
    "$fanfictionId-$chapterId",
    ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
    OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DownloaderWorker::class.java)
        .addTag(fanfictionId)
```

I retrieve my livedata like this :

```
fun getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(
    fanfictionId: String
): LiveData<List<WorkInfo>> {
    return workManager.getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(fanfictionId)
}
```

I know that the work is running perfectly, the problem is that when I observe my livedata :

```
Transformations.map(apiRepository.getDownloadState(fanfictionId)) { workInfo ->
    val isCurrentlySyncing = workInfo.any { it.state in listOf(ENQUEUED, RUNNING) }
    FFLogger.d(EVENT_KEY, "isSyncing $isCurrentlySyncing")
    isSyncing.postValue(isCurrentlySyncing)
}
```

This code is never triggered, I never see the log "isSyncing..."

So... the workmanager does its job, I just can't see its progression. It used to work on an earlier version of the code, and I don't see any difference that could explain this...

Any help is welcome, thx

Comment: Now there are lots of limitation specially after the android 10 and China devices , which kill work job on background

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that, the problem is that the job works, I have a visual representation on my screen as the 20+ chapters are getting downloaded.